# using atom-minify to search and replace before minify on save

Tags: atom-editor, minify

Hi im using `atom` and `atom-minify`

I would like to remove all references to `https://websiteaddress.com` but only in the minified file.

I only know html and css, but I came across inline-parameters where i can add some code to the top of the page and `atom-minify` will run it.

[image]

[I found this](https://flight-manual.atom.io/api/v1.0.19/TextEditor/#instance-scan):
`::scan(regex, iterator)` which makes sense but how do I input this

Here is my best guess for what to put at the top of each page in atom, any help would be much appreciated:

`/* minifyOnSave, scan(https://websiteaddress.com, replace) */`

Comment: I had an idea for an alternative option of creating a .bat file with a find and replace .min files for the url reference. I think a .bat file will be easier for me to work out.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Atom's built in search and replace feature [image]

The default keybind for this is ctrl-f or command-f if you are on mac.

Comment: I want to make this an automatic feature when saved, so it removes the url in the `.min` file.